# Trouble matching words with -like in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, string-matching

My code isn't working right, it's supposed to take a floating "this" or "that" and decide if it matches one of the mentioned words, however it is currently stopping at the first `if` statement and saying all the words match it, which they definitely don't. I've tried `-match`, `-eq`, `-like` .... I placed an "x" in front of the incorrect line. This is only a short line of a much larger code. (BRC - Bulk rename utility(commandline))

```powershell
if ($this){
    #exceptions
    if ($that -like "Drücker" -or "Biegekern" -or "Führung" -or "Pressentisch"){Write-Host ("x($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"3_$that":"3_$this ($that)" /REPLACECI:_Dr.Pos.:"_$this ($that)_Pos_" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
    }
    elseif ($that -like "Halteplatte" -or "Oberteil" -or "Unterteil" -or "Schieber"){Write-Host ("($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"3_$that":"3_$this ($that)" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"2_$that":"2_$this ($that)" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
    }
    elseif ($that -like "Schnitt"){Write-Host ("($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"0_$that":"0_$this ($that)" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
    }
    elseif ($that -like "Zusatzführung"){Write-Host ("($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"2_$that":"2_$this ($that)" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
    }

    #main renaming function
    elseif ($that){
        Write-Host ("($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
        .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"_$that":"_$this ($that)" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
    }
}
elseif ($that){
    Write-Host ("($i/$rowMax) Blank-Skip")
    $blanks=$blanks+1
}
else {
    $i=$rowMax
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meh people make mistakes. I make tonnes! Best way to learn. Since multiple criteria to match `$that` against something like this might be a better fit. Simple regex with the same logic

```powershell
if ($that -match "(Drücker|Biegekern|Führung|Pressentisch)"){
    Do-Stuff()
}
```

If you reacted differently to the matches then a switch would be a better fit.

```powershell
switch ($that) 
    { 
        Drücker {"wo sind meine Hosen."} 
        Biegekern {"meinem Hologramm ist voller Ohren."} 
        Führung {"mein Deutsch ist nicht gut."} 
        Pressentisch {"Zwei."} 
        default {"keine Ahnung."}
    }
```

Other more complex examples of switch which would help can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493731/whats-the-powershell-syntax-for-multiple-values-in-a-switch-statement). An example using both of the snippets above would be this

```powershell
$that = "Zusatzführung"

switch -Regex ($that) 
    { 
        "^(Drücker|Biegekern|Führung|Pressentisch)$" {"wo sind meine Hosen."} 
        "^(Halteplatte|Oberteil|Unterteil|Schieber)$" {"meinem Hologramm ist voller Ohren."} 
        "Schnitt" {"mein Deutsch ist nicht gut."} 
        "Zusatzführung" {"Zwei."} 
        default {"keine Ahnung."}
    }
```

`$that` in this case would have matched the first entry. If you are looking for complete word matches you could just use `^$` as I have done. You could also use the `break` keyword to prevent multiple entries from matching.

```powershell
....
"(Drücker|Biegekern|Führung|Pressentisch)" {"wo sind meine Hosen."; Break} 
"Zusatzführung" {"Zwei."}
....
```

Using the same `$that` with the above lines would only match the first. Then after the output line we exit the switch.

Comment: Yay for pimping out `Switch`! Such a very under utilized cmdlet imho.

Comment: I wish I could use this solution, but the trouble is I need to match $that to exactly one of those words, and then process to do the exact same thing for all the words of that category. As the list of words gets longer, though, I'm considering making an array of words, but I think I'd run into the same situation as with your code...

Comment: @joebredestege If you are interested I will take your code and convert it to a swtich statement and you can see it in action.

Comment: @joebredestege. Have a look at what is there now.

Comment: you sir, just saved me alot of writing xD 
But note the syntax is actually break, not return

Comment: Updated the answer to use the proper keyword

Answer (score 0):

Simply put to make this work you need to rewrite -like and -or. I'm just a dingus

```
if ($that -like "Drücker" -or $that -like "Biegekern" -or $that -like "Führung" -or $that -like "Pressentisch"){Write-Host ("x($i/$rowMax) Replacing $that with $this")
                    .\BRC32 /DIR:$directory /INCLR /RECURSIVE /quiet /IGNOREFILEX /REPLACECI:"3_$that":"3_$this ($that)" /REPLACECI:_Dr.Pos.:"_$this ($that)_Pos_" /replaceci:" ":_ /execute
                }
```

Comment: And unless I'm mistaken, the reason is that your first version evaluates to ($that -like "...") -or (...), and all the string literals evaluate to "truthy" values.