# Powershell to display duplicate files

Tags: powershell

I have a task to check if new files are imported for the day in a shared location folder and alert if any duplicate files and no recursive check needed.

Below code displays all the file details with size which are 1 day old However I need only files with the same size as I cannot compare them using name.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Script\test |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}

$Files | Select-Object -Property Name, hash, LastWriteTime, @{N='SizeInKb';E={[double]('{0:N2}' -f ($_.Length/1kb))}}
```

Comment: What if two files have the same size but different names?
Will that be considered as a duplicate?

Comment: as two files in a same folder cannot have the same name I am considering size to detect duplicates, Let me know if any other ideas

Comment: @Teja554 does the answer solve your problem?

Comment: hey tukan your answer looks great , unfortunately my powershell version is 2.0 and hence am unable to use Get-FileHash. Working to call the method from local.

Answer (score 25):

I didn't like the big DOS-like script answer written here, so here's an idiomatic way of doing it for *Powershell*:

From the folder you want to find the duplicates, just run this simple set of pipes

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File `
| Group-Object -Property Length `
| ?{ $_.Count -gt 1 } `
| %{ $_.Group } `
| Get-FileHash `
| Group-Object -Property Hash `
| ?{ $_.Count -gt 1 } `
| %{ $_.Group }
```

Which will show all files and their hashes that match other files.
Each line does the following:

- get files

  - from current directory (use `-Path $directory` otherwise)
  - recursively (if not wanted, remove `-Recurse`)
- group based on file size
- discard groups with less than 2 files
- grab all those files
- get hashes for each
- group based on hash
- discard groups with less than 2 files
- get all those files

Add  `| %{ $_.path }` to just show the paths instead of the hashes.
Add  `| %{ $_.path -replace "$([regex]::escape($(pwd)))",'' }` to only show the relative path from the current directory (useful in recursion).

For the question-asker specifically, don't forget to whack in `| Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}` after the `gci` so you're not comparing files you don't want to consider, which might get very time-consuming if you have a lot of coincidentally same-length files in that shared folder.

Finally, if you're like me and just wanted to find dupes based on name, as google will probably take you here too:

`gci -Recurse -file | Group-Object name | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | select -ExpandProperty group | %{ $_.fullname }`

Comment: This is one of the best one-line I've seen in PowerShell +1 man !

Answer (score 2):

All the examples here take in account only timestamp, lenght and name.  That is for sure not enough.

Imagine this example
You have two files:
`c:\test_path\test.txt` and `c:\test_path\temp\text.txt`. 
The first one contains `12345`.  The second contains `54321`.  In this case these files will be considered identical even when they are not.

I have create a duplicate checker based on hash calculation.  It was created right now from my head so it is rather crude (but I think you get the idea and it will be easy to optimize):

**Edit** I've decided the source code was "too crude" (nick name for incorrect) and I have improved it (removed superfluous code):

```
# The current directory where the script is executed
$path = (Resolve-Path .\).Path

$hash_details = @{}
$duplicities = @{}    

# Remove unique record by size (different size = different hash)
# You can select only those you need with e.g. "*.jpg"
$file_names = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Include "*.*" | ? {( ! $_.PSIsContainer)} | Group Length | ? {$_.Count -gt 1} | Select -Expand Group | Select FullName, Length 

# I'm using SHA256 due to SHA1 collisions found
$hash_details =  ForEach ($file in $file_names) {
                             Get-FileHash -Path $file.Fullname -Algorithm SHA256
                         }

# just counter for the Hash table key
$counter = 0
ForEach ($first_file_hash in $hash_details) {
    ForEach ($second_file_hash in $hash_details) {
        If (($first_file_hash.hash -eq $second_file_hash.hash) -and ($first_file_hash.path -ne $second_file_hash.path)) {
                $duplicities.add($counter, $second_file_hash)
                $counter += 1
        }
    }
}

##Throw output with duplicity files 
If ($duplicities.count -gt 0) { 
    #Write-Output $duplicities.values
    Write-Output "Duplicate files found:" $duplicities.values.Path
    $duplicities.values | Out-file -Encoding UTF8 duplicate_log.txt
} Else {
    Write-Output 'No duplicities found'
}
```

I have created a test structure:

```
PS C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities> Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse


    Directory: C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          9.4.2018      9:58            test
-a---          9.4.2018     11:06       2067 check_for_duplicities.ps1
-a---          9.4.2018     11:06        757 duplicate_log.txt


    Directory: C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          9.4.2018      9:58            identical_file
d----          9.4.2018      9:56            t
-a---          9.4.2018      9:55          5 test.txt


    Directory: C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\identical_file


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          9.4.2018      9:55          5 test.txt


    Directory: C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\t


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          9.4.2018      9:55          5 test.txt
```

(Where file in the ..\duplicities\test\t is different from the others).

The result of the running script.

The console output:

```
PS C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities> .\check_for_duplicities.ps1
Duplicate files found:
C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\identical_file\test.txt
C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\test.txt
```

The *duplicate_log.txt* file contains more detailed information:

```
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path                                                                                              
---------       ----                                                                   ----                                                                                              
SHA256          5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5       C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\identical_file\test.txt             
SHA256          5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5       C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\_file_operations\duplicities\test\test.txt
```

**Conclusion**

As you see the different file is correctly omitted from the result set.

Answer (score -1):

Since the file contents that you are determining to be duplicate. It's more prudent to just hash files and compare the hash.

The name, size. timestamp would not be a prudent attributes for the defined use case. Since the hash would tell you if the files have the same content.

See these discussions

> Need a way to check if two files are the same?  Calculate a hash of
>   the files.  Here is one way to do it:
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/25/duplicate-files
>
> Duplicate File Finder and Remover
>
> And now the moment you have been waiting for....an all PowerShell file
>   duplicate finder and remover! Now you can clean up all those copies of
>   pictures, music files, and videos. The script opens a file dialog box
>   to select the target folder, recursively scans each file for duplica
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Duplicate-File-Finder-and-78f40ae9

Comment: Some code here would be helpful.  If the external links die nothing will be left here.

Answer (score -1):

This might helpful for you.

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\SC' | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Group-Object -Property Length
foreach($filegroup in $allfiles)
{
if ($filegroup.Count -ne 1)
{
    foreach ($file in $filegroup.Group)
    {
        Invoke-Item $file.fullname
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How does that help with duplicities?  Dates and sizes are not valid information for checking duplicities.

Comment: If you see the question, They are looking for the script to find out files which are same length ?

Comment: I read the question and the text to the question.  Imagine this example you have two files (with identical timestamp) paths `c:\test_path\test.txt` and `c:\test_path\temp\text.txt`.   One with `12345` contents and second with `54321` are they identical in your code or not?

Comment: Not mentioning, you are not commenting the code at all!