# Does bash have a `default`-equivalent for the case statement when using fallthrough?

Tags: bash, switch-statement, fall-through

```
case "$action" in
a|b)
    echo for a or b
;;&
b|c)
    echo for c or b
;;&
*)
    echo for everything ELSE
;;&
esac
```

So, as you can see, I'm using `;;&` instead of `;;` so that if `action=b` it will trigger both of the first two cases.
However, a drawback of this is that `*)` no longer 'means' "everything else", but will match "everything" instead; thus `b` will trigger the final one also.

PowerShell is able to do what I want because it has a dedicated `default` keyword, does Bash have something similar?
What about an exhaustive work-around like `[!(a|b|c)])` or something?

It would have been handy to do something like `case 5 in 4) echo bob; ;;& esac || echo DEFAULT` but `case` doesn't seem to return any code.

Answer (score 10):

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> If the ‘;;’ operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match. Using ‘;&’ in place of ‘;;’ causes execution to continue with the command-list associated with the next clause, if any. Using ‘;;&’ in place of ‘;;’ causes the shell to test the patterns in the next clause, if any, and execute any associated command-list on a successful match, continuing the case statement execution as if the pattern list had not matched.

Maybe such idea:

```
case "$action" in
a|b)
    echo for a or b
    ;;&
b|c)
    echo for c or b
    ;;&
a|b|c) ;;
*)
    echo for everything ELSE
esac
```

Comment: that's what I have (original pre-edit post had a typo)

I need to fix the final statement, it should trigger for "everything ELSE", but is triggering for "everything"

Comment: So just use `;;` ... It's designed to work that way... I don't understand, then why do you use a fallthrough if you don't want it to fallthrough? Please post some sample inputs and example outputs for the inputs. Maybe make the second `;;&` a `;;`? That way `*)` will not execute if `b` is matched.

Comment: Then you lose the `a|b)` -> `b|c)`, the whole point of the question. It's specifically asking for the ability to use both, which other languages I've needed it in have

Comment: I do want fallthrough, but I dont want fallthrough-`*)`, I want `default`. `*)` is a hack because bash doesnt have `default`, but they're the same thing when not using fallthrough. This question is: "but what if I am using fallthrough? What's my default-equivalent?"

Comment: To account for your edit; if you only change the second `;;&` to `;;` that makes the final one mean "not b|c", which is not the same as "everything else" id est "not a|b|c".

Comment: haha, we got the same idea in the end. I'll delete my answer since you did it first (I didn't see it), but I'll only add an upvote. I'm really looking for a default-equivalent

Comment: for anyone else coming in, I'll quote my deleted answer; "But I'd appreciate a way not to re-list all the other options (so if I edit in more switches, I don't need to remember to add it to the list at the end)."