# Searching for PowerShell syntax for multiple enum values in the case block of a switch statement?

Tags: powershell, enums, switch-statement

An example of what I want to do:

```
    enum Fruit {
        Apple
        Banana
        Orange
    }

    $myFruit = [Fruit]::$UsrString

    switch ($myFruit) {
        Apple, Orange {
        Write-Host "This is an apple or an orange"
        break
        }
        Banana {
        Write-Host "This is a banana"
        break
        }
        default {
        Write-Host "Unknown fruit: $myFruit"
        break
        }
    }
```

**But each attempt I have made has yet to work as intended, if at all**.

I have searched for anything to do with **Powershell**, **switch-statements**, and **enums** but have yet to find the answer.

I have reviewed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493731/whats-the-powershell-syntax-for-multiple-values-in-a-switch-statement) on StackOverflow.

I have successfully used the "switch -regEx (someEnum)" as long as I use the integer values of the enum items. However, that essentially defeats the use of the enum (ie. labeled ints).

*My intent* was to keep the switch as efficient as possible (ie. switching on simple int values; staying away from the more common string-compare style PS switch usage, just to keep performance up).

**Does the multi-item case block syntax exist for enum usage in powershell?**

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: You would need to use script block conditions and bitwise operator for this to work as you intend

Comment: @iRon just an FYI, that is the link referenced in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

- does *not* support *multiple* branch conditions, but ...
- *does* support using a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as a branch condition, inside of which you're free to perform any test, including for multiple values, using the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the input value at hand.

Therefore:

```
switch ($myFruit) {
  { $_ -in 'Apple', 'Orange' } {
    "This is an apple or an orange"
    break
  }
  Banana {
    "This is a banana"
    break
  }
  default {
    "Unknown fruit: $_"
  }
}
```

Note:

- As you can see in the `default` branch's *action* script block above, `$_` also refers to the input value there.

  - Using `$_` is generally preferable, as the `switch` input value can be an *array* (list-like collection), in which case the branches are evaluated *for each element* (and `$_` then refers to the element at hand.
  - With an array as input, use `continue` in lieu of `break` in an action script block in order to continue processing with the *next element* (`break` will prevent processing of further elements).
- Note that even though the `[Fruit]` enumeration values are compared against *strings*, the comparison works, because PowerShell conveniently automatically converts enumeration values to and from their string representations.